# Display data from multiple endpoints using redux and table

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to display data from multiple sources into one table using redux. example data

```
url:'/product/'
products :[
    {
        id: 1,
        name:'machine gun',
        category: 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name:'water pistol',
        category: 2
    },
    
    
]
endpoint:'/category/'
category:[
    {
        id:1,
        name:'main tool'
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:'secret weapon'
    }
]
endpoint:'/stock/?product=1,current=true'
stock:[
    {
        id:1,
        product:1,
        current:false,
        currentStock:10
    },

]
```

Store->1) products 2) category 3) stock

my problems are:

1. If i query all the categories and stocks and product from the backend, it will be very expensive
2. i want the table to have field as per under
   |productName|Category|quantityinStock|
   kindly help
   this is my sample actions to fetch productstock

   ```
    export function getStock(productId) {

    const request = axios.get('http://localhost:8000/productstock/',
        {
        params: {
            product: productId,
            current: true
        }
    }
    );

    return dispatch =>
        request.then(response =>
            dispatch({
                type: GET_STOCK,
                payload: response.data
            })
        );
   ```

   }

Comment: Then you need to change your BE.

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking. Do you want to load data partially? or how to call different APIs sequentially?

Comment: My question is simple, how can i display a table as under

Comment: |productName|CategoryName|quantityinStock|

Comment: What have you tried before posting this question?

Comment: I tried the following steps:

Comment: 1) Fetch all products 2) Fetch all categories(very expensive) 3) iterate throuh the products using mapfunction and find categories associated with category id 4) tried the same thing for the productstock